# Feature Normalization for classification (SVM)

Tags: machine-learning, normalization

I have some questions about Normalization: 
When you extract features and you want to normalize your features before classification.
How do you do normalize the features ( e.g. the two classes you have)? 
1- Do you normalize each class seperatly? or you normalize the two classes together?
2- Do you normalize the whole data before spliting trianing and testing ? or you normalize training first , then normalize each new testing sample separately? 
3- Any Reference? book or paper?

Answer (score 0):

```
*Do you normalize the whole data before spliting trianing and testing ?*
```

**There is no need to split the data for training and testing**

**Code :**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandarScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_y = StandardScaler()
x = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)
```

thanks